# Looping regression with conditions to remove specific coefficients

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

So I understand how to do a stepwise regression, for instance:

```
fit <- step(lm(y~x, data=df)
```

Is there a way to create a loop that would work as follows:

```
1) stepwise regression - call it "fit"
2) re-run stepwise regression excluding coefficients > 1,000 from "fit"
3) continue process until all coefficients are <= 1,000
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for the 'direction' argument inside 'step'. In addition, try to look here: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/154-stepwise-regression-essentials-in-r/

Comment: Not direction, specifically a logical loop where I run a stepwise regression on the entire data set as a first step. Than create an if statement where all coefficients in absolute terms that are greater than 1,000 in value should be removed an another regression is to be re-run. And continue this process until all coefficients are under 1,000 in absolute terms. PS. I read that.

Comment: Use a `while` loop, then you can extract the coefficients from the fitted model with `names(coef(fit)[which(coef(fit)>=1000)])` and remove them from your data